# net_ssh on production returns 'Authentication Failed' using public keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, ubuntu, net-ssh

I am trying to execute couple of commands on remote server and as authentication method, I am using public keys.

Public keys are configured properly on server and I can connect to it without system prompting me for password like this:

```
ssh root@example.com
```

So this is what I do in my code:

```
Net::SSH.start(host, user, :keys=>["~/.ssh/id_rsa","~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"]) do |ssh|
  ssh.exec "service nginx reload"
end
```

On local machine, everything works properly, when on production server, I get an error.

```
Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: Authentication failed for user root@example.com
```

I did some Googling and I had already tried to fallback to net_ssh 2.7.0, yet no luck, same issue. I also tried to replace relative path to absolute, in my case /root/.ssh/...
I tried adding an option

```
:auth_methods => ['publickey']
```

yet still, no luck.

I am also certain that the keys reside in correct paths.

***EDIT 1***

Worth noting that this works perfectly well when run in production rails console.

***EDIT 2***

Symptoms here are similar with ones in this question: [Net::SSH works from production rails console, AuthenticationFailed from production webapp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7533170/netssh-works-from-production-rails-console-authenticationfailed-from-producti?rq=1)
with exception that my app runs from root and there shouldn't be permission issues because of that.

***EDIT 3***

I had temporary fallen back to password auth that works fine but I'd really like to use key auth instead.

Any help on this issue is much appreciated.

Comment: you're running as root? (this is a really bad idea) when it goes owned they get whole box.  can you look at the logs on the far end. also :keys is only for the private keys, I don't think you need the public key in there as it isn't used for for connecting, and that could be messing it up

Comment: I tried removing keys option entirely, same effect, doesn't work.
on auth.log there is nothing related to an attempt of this server to connect to another.